# How to embed a file or text to c# project dll at build time in visual studio?

Tags: c#, build, build-events, dynamics-al

I need to embed a file/text to c# project dll at build time.
I have tried following ways to do it:
Consider I am having a c# project **MyProject**,

1. I have created a **Support.exe** which actually creates a **Resource.resx** file and embeds the file to by updating **MyProject.csproj**. I called this **support.exe** in pre-build event of **Myproject**. But it did not embed the file to **MyProject.dll**. If I do a rebuild, the files were embeded.
2. Another way, I have used Assembly Linker to embed a file to the dll. I called the command **al /out:MyProject.dll /embed:filename** in post-build event of **MyProject**. But the assembly linker creates a new dll and it does not included the **MyProject.cs** file.

Is there any other ways to embed a file to c# project dll at buildtime ?

Thanks in advance !